# Oracle TNS Permission Denied *

Tags: zend-framework, oracle10g, centos6

I'm using:

- CentOS 6.7
- Zend.1.2.15 using oci8, using instantclient 11.2 x64
- PHP 5.4.45

Trying to connect to an Oracle:

- Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0

Already checked credentials, already tried to connet to other Oracle server but the error still the same:

```
12546 ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied *
```

Already gave 0777 permission to `/usr/local/oracle/11.2/client64/` following some answer around but none of them solved.

Server does not have the IP in any sort of blacklist.

The same code runs in any other Windows PC with OracleInstantClient and no further configuration was needed on the server about giving an IP permissions to access or any permission at all.

Is there something more that I can check to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're picking up the instant client - you don't have a full client installed on that machine that it's seeing first?

Comment: @AlexPoole from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html, installed files were:  oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm  and   oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you have installed instant client; but did you already have the full client, perhaps? Can you see which Oracle binaries and libraries PHP is actually using? I'm asking because I know you can get that error with the full client (or server) software when the permissions are wrong, but I don't know how to get it with the instant client. Just a wild guess though.

Comment: I don't think I have a full client, no. As far as I can tell, PHP is using oci8 as library. Is there any command that I should run to check if full client is installed? Not an UNIX expert.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After hours searching I found this article: http://www.emsperformance.net/2013/12/20/connecting-to-oracle-database-from-php-with-oci8/ which is by far the best article explaining the installation process of LAMP, Oracle, Zend.

The setting I was missing is:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Edit: After a while this answer still looks useful to someone, worths to say that this happens because the machine has SELinux activated, usually in the `enforcing` mode. I would not recommend to disable SELinux, but setting it to `permissive` looks to ease the process of identifying some problems with it. You can check SELinux status by `sestatus`.

A full list of booleans on SELinux is available at: https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Overall information: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: i have using it, then it's solved my problem, one tips from me, if you have a laravel 7 / centos 7 / oci8, just use  setsebool  httpd_can_network_connect on